# Sec_Axis for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am facing a few issues regarding the `sec.axis`. The following is my code. I'm trying to plot the Asking price on the left side and the Area on the right side with the x-axis showing the District. Both the values can be shown on the graph but the Area values are not distributing according to the secondary axis, it's still showing display according to the primary Y-axis.

picture:

[image]

```
ggplot(df2,mapping = aes(x=District.))+ 
    geom_bar(aes(y=Asking/1000),stat="identity") + 
    geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=District., y=Area, group=1), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .*0.4, name = "Area")) +
    theme_light() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1), 
    axis.text.y  = element_text(color = 'green'), 
    axis.title.y = element_text(color='green'), 
    axis.text.y.right =  element_text(color = 'blue'),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color='blue'))
```

Comment: Please edit the question by providing `dput(df2)`. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that your secondary y-axis is still a transformation of the primary y-axis.  It is not an independent y-axis. For more details, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales).  Also, you need to define `y=Area*2` in `geom_line()`, as you are defining `sec_axis(~ .*0.4,...)`.  You can see Sebastian Rothbucher's explanation in the same link.